# How to remove labels from bing maps but keep borders using developer tool (inspect element))

Tags: bing-maps, bing

[image]

How to remove labels from bing maps but keep borders using developer tool (inspect element))

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to edit the map on the Bing.com website as the map object isn't accessible from the console. If you use the Bing Maps developer SDK, you can customize the map style to remove the labels and leave the borders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/custom-map-styles-in-bing-maps